# Insert a table variable into a temp table with multiple columns (ID, Number, etc.)

Tags: sql, sql-server, global-variables, temp-tables

I need to insert multiple Table variables into one temp table.

One of the table variables is:

```
DECLARE @@TempTable_Number TABLE (Number bigint) 

insert into  @@TempTable_Number (Number) values ('000000000000');
insert into  @@TempTable_Number (Number) values ('100000000000');
```

This works for inserting just one table variable

```
select * into ##GlobalTempTable_1 from @@TempTable_Number
```

I have a couple more table variables like

```
DECLARE @@TempTable_ID TABLE (Number int) 

insert into  @@TempTable_ID (ID) values ('1');
insert into  @@TempTable_ID (ID) values ('12');
```

etc...

I tried this to insert data from multiple table variables into one TempTable:

```
Select * into  ####GlobalTempTable_1 From @@TempTable_ID,  @@TempTable_Number;
```

The query goes to a continuous loop...

**EDIT:**

One of the table variables is:

```
DECLARE @@TempTable_Number TABLE (Number bigint, ID int) 

insert into  @@gvTempTable (Number) values ('21212321332332');
insert into  @@gvTempTable (Number) values ('100000000000');
insert into  @@gvTempTable (ID) values ('1');
insert into  @@gvTempTable (ID) values ('12');

select * into ##GlobalTempTable from @@gvTempTable;
select * from ##GlobalTempTable;
```

This returns a kind of a cartesian product

[image: Result sets]

Comment: Your example is odd. First you store `bigint/int` but provide strings. Not big deal (implicit conversion will handle it). Second your `@@TempTable_ID` has invalid `INSERT INTO` statement (column names `Number` <>`ID`).

Comment: It is a typo, I meat to use ID in the second column. I updated my question, thanks again.

Comment: Please do not edit question,like you did, becaue you invalidate existing answers. If you want to add clarification mark it clearly. Second your edit is a new question and should be asked separately.

Answer (score 3):

Use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT ID
INTO  ##GlobalTempTable_1 
FROM @@TempTable_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT Number
FROM @@TempTable_Number;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/VIO81950)**</kbd>

---

> ```
> Select * into  ####GlobalTempTable_1 From @@TempTable_ID,  @@TempTable_Number;
> ```
>
> *The query goes to a continuous loop...*

It is probably not loop but very long query. Keep in mind that you do `Cartesian product`.

So your query is the same as:

```
SELECT * 
INTO  ##GlobalTempTable_1 
FROM @@TempTable_ID
CROSS JOIN  @@TempTable_Number;
```

And the result is `NxM` records where `N` is number of records in first table and `M` in the second.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But It produces a different from what I'm expecting result. I modified my previous query I got really close, but not 100%

Comment: I did the following: DECLARE @@TempTable TABLE (Number bigint, ID int) 
insert into  @@gvTempTable (Number) values ('00000000000000');
insert into  @@gvTempTable (Number) values ('00000000000012');
insert into  @@gvTempTable (ID) values ('1');
insert into  @@gvTempTable (ID) values ('12'); Select * into ##TempTable From @@gvTempTable

Comment: The result set still returns Cartesian Product in two columns, but I need it to return ID and NUMBER as one row not return NULLs for all IDs and then for all Numbers separately.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (
    ID INT
    ,Number BIGINT
    )

INSERT INTO @TempTable (Number)
VALUES ('21212321332332');

INSERT INTO @TempTable (Number)
VALUES ('100000000000');

INSERT INTO @TempTable (ID)
VALUES ('1');

INSERT INTO @TempTable (ID)
VALUES ('12');

--select * into #GlobalTempTable from @@gvTempTable;
--select * from ##GlobalTempTable;
SELECT *
FROM @TempTable

SELECT A.ID
    ,B.Number
FROM (
    SELECT ID
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY ID
            ) TempId
    FROM @TempTable
    WHERE id IS NOT NULL
    ) A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT number
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY id
            ) TempId
    FROM @TempTable
    WHERE number IS NOT NULL
    ) B ON A.TempId = B.TempId
```